# Replacing null values in powerquery column with value from cell above

Tags: excel, null, powerquery

I have a series of workbooks I import data from via PowerQuery.

The source files only have the `Date` field completed every 4th row. There are 3 site specific entries for each date.

The markdown table below shows what currently happens when I load the workbook data via PowerQuery:

```
| Date       | Site | ItemA | ItemB |
|------------|------|-------|-------|
| 01/01/2016 | A    | 19    | 17    |
| null       | B    | 11    | 5     |
| null       | C    | 30    | 22    |
| 02/01/2016 | A    | 16    | 17    |
| null       | B    | 5     | 5     |
| null       | C    | 21    | 22    |
| 03/01/2016 | A    | 15    | 17    |
| null       | B    | 9     | 5     |
| null       | C    | 24    | 22    |
```

I want to be able to replace each `null` row in the `Date` column, with the value of the row above, so that dates appear in every row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table.FillDown:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt260754.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

There's a button for this operation in the Transform tab of the Query Editor.